# UIImage does not scroll in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am new to iPhone developer,

I want scrolling in my Image,

Here is my code snippet,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"]];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image1.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;

 [self centerScrollViewContents];
}


- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that you want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}
```

also `bg.png` is not getting applied to my background.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: I want scrolling in my Image, whats the mistake ?

Comment: well, actually you are not scrolling the image, not even the imageView, you are scrolling the srollView.

Comment: And make sure the contentSize of the scroll is greater than the frame of the scroll, otherwise there will be noting to scroll as all the content will be matching the frame size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer is actually a combination of many of the other answers & comments, plus some other adjustments.

1. as Pan said, you need to set your scrollView delegate.  otherwise, your
   viewForZoomingInScrollView: delegate implementation won't get called.
   i've provided this call in viewDidLoad: , though you can also hook this
   up in interface builder or storyboard.
2. as Teodor Carstea said in the comments to the original post, in your
   original  code, you are setting your `.imageView.size` and your
   `.scrollView.contentsSize` to exactly the same thing.  you don't need
   the code that sets the `.imageView.frame.`  that will happen as part of
   `initWithImage:` .  and this will make the sizes different.
3. you do need to set the `.scrollView.contentSize` to the `image.size` .
   it sort of matters where ou do this, at least in terms of that it must
   happen prior to setting the zoom scale.
4. as Kunal Balani mentioned, you have to have scrollingEnabled, though you
   can set this in storyboard or interface builder.
5. as MidhunMP said, you have to have `.userInteractionEnabled = YES`, though
   generally, these are the defaults that get set in storyboard/Interface Builder,
   so i'm not going to include them in the code changes below.
6. your method `centerScrollViewContents` isn't really *centering* the contents
   as much as it is re-shaping the imageView frame.  i've simply commented out
   the call, because i think it's completely unnecessary.  instead, i've made
   a simple call to start your image in the upper left corner.
7. if you only want to scroll, setting the `zoomScale`, `minimumZoomScale` and
   `maximumZoomScale` is not necessary.  if you also want to pinch-zoom, then
   you will need to set all three of these, and in the proper places.
8. you do seem to want to stretch the view if it is smaller than the content
   bounds.  if this is truly a concern (i.e. if you know your bg.png is so
   small that it needs to be stretched), then calculate the contentFrame to
   image frame width ratio and height ratio separately, and whichever of 
   these is larger will be your new zoomScale, and you'll be able to scroll
   in the other direction.  or, there are other ways to decide how you want
   that scale set.  search stackoverflow.com for other answers for setting
   the zoom scale as desired.

here's the code after applying these items.

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;         // can be set in storyboard
    self.scrollView.scrollingEnabled = YES;  // can be set in storyboard
    NSString* bgPng
      = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bgPng];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
//  self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image1.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;

    // set zoom scale here if desired.

    // if zoom is implemented, the following call should be made
    // after setting .zoomScale, .minimumZoomScale & .maximumZoomScale
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;

//  [self centerScrollViewContents];
}


//- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
//    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
//    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;
//
//    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
//        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
//    } else {
//        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
//    }
//
//    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
//        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
//    } else {
//        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
//    }
//  
//    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
//}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Return the view that you want to zoom
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well, try this :

```
UIImageView *tempImgv = [[[UIImageView alloc]init] autorelease];
    [tempImgv setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/bg.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]]]];
    [tempImgv setFrame:your_desired_frame];
    self.imageView = tempImgv;
    [self.scrollWiew setContentSize: size_greater_than_scroll_frame];
    [self.scrollWiew addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Comment: not working. But when i write this it gets working `self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"]]];`

Comment: could you tell me the size of your imageview and the size of image?

Comment: size of image is equal to screen size.

Comment: so what you want to scroll if you assign the image size to content size of the scroll?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your scrollview frame . Scrolling will be enabled only when frame size is < contentsize. Because if all the content is visible in frame then why do you need scrolling at all ??

try this :

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                 self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //init with whatever frame you have

  scroll.scrollEnabled = YES // this is imp ... don't ignore this

   //whatever your code is 

    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;// this is wrong

    //contentSize property to the size of the scrollable content. This specifies the size of the scrollable area.
    // do this
    self.scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the user interaction enabled property of image view and scroll view to yes.
Please check with this code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"]];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image1.size};
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;

    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
```

And if you need to set the image as your scroll view's background, use this:`self.scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"]]];`

Comment: I need scroll in my image what changes should i do in your code ?

Comment: you can set your image as the background image of the scroll view or you can add the image as a sub view to your scroll view. If you need to cover the entire scroll view the first option is good.

Comment: @Krunal: please check my answer above :) It'll work else post your comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you have provided

```
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg.png"]];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1];
    self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image1.size};
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

The content size of scrollView which you are setting is equal to the size of the image i.e the above bolded code. Try with the following code.

```
CGSize sizeOfScroll = image.size;
sizeOfScroll.width *= 1.5f;
sizeOfScroll.height *= 1.5f;

self.scrollView.contentSize = sizeOfScroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

scrolling the images

```
scroll.userinteractionEnable = YES;
```

and other then,

```
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, you need to set the minimum and maximum zoom scale.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the scrollview delegate somewhere else?
Like this: `self.scrollView.delegate = self;`